# Ошибка при компиляции Java ZoneId.of(ZoneId.java:411)

Tags: java

Выдает такие ошибки:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.zone.ZoneRulesException: Unknown time-zone ID: Europe/France                            
        at java.time.zone.ZoneRulesProvider.getProvider(ZoneRulesProvider.java:272)
        at java.time.zone.ZoneRulesProvider.getRules(ZoneRulesProvider.java:227) 
        at java.time.ZoneRegion.ofId(ZoneRegion.java:120)                                                                    
        at java.time.ZoneId.of(ZoneId.java:411)                                                                              
        at java.time.ZoneId.of(ZoneId.java:359)                                                                              
        at Clock.clock(Prog.java:21)                                                                                         
        at Main.main(Main.java:15)
```

Вот код

```
import java.io.IOException; 
import java.util.Scanner; 
 
public class Main 
{ 
    static Clock clock; 
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    { 
        clock = new Clock(); 
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); 
        System.out.println("Enter the locale: "); 
        clock.location = in.next(); 
        System.out.println("Enter delay: "); 
        clock.delay = in.nextInt(); 
        clock.clock();
    } 
}
```

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent; 
import java.awt.event.KeyListener; 
import java.io.BufferedWriter; 
import java.io.FileWriter; 
import java.io.IOException; 
import java.time.LocalDateTime; 
import java.time.ZoneId; 
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter; 
import java.util.Scanner; 
 
class Clock 
{ 
    public int delay; 
    public String location; 
 
    public void clock() throws IOException 
    { 
        while (true) 
        { 
            DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"); 
            LocalDateTime localdatetime = LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.of(location)); 
 
            String Date_Time = "\n" + location + " " + 
            localdatetime.format(formatter) + "\n" + 
            "In the binary system : " + Integer.toBinaryString(localdatetime.getDayOfMonth()) + 
            " " + Integer.toBinaryString(localdatetime.getMonthValue()) + 
            " " + Integer.toBinaryString(localdatetime.getYear()) + 
            " " + Integer.toBinaryString(localdatetime.getHour()) + 
            " " + Integer.toBinaryString(localdatetime.getMinute()) + 
            " " + Integer.toBinaryString(localdatetime.getSecond()) + "\n" + 
            "In the hexadecimal system : " + Integer.toHexString(localdatetime.getDayOfMonth()) + 
            " " + Integer.toHexString(localdatetime.getMonthValue()) + 
            " " + Integer.toHexString(localdatetime.getYear()) + 
            " " + Integer.toHexString(localdatetime.getHour()) + 
            " " + Integer.toHexString(localdatetime.getMinute()) + 
            " " + Integer.toHexString(localdatetime.getSecond()); 
 
            System.out.println(Date_Time); 
 
            try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("src/com/lab/Results.txt", true)) 
            { 
                writer.write(Date_Time); 
                writer.write('\n'); 
            } 
            catch (IOException ex) 
            { 
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage()); 
            } 
 
            try 
            { 
                Thread.sleep(delay * 1000); 
                if (System.in.available() !=0) 
                { 
                    break; 
                } 
            } 
            catch (InterruptedException e) 
            { } 
        } 
    } 
}
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Попробуйте вместо Europe/France задавать Europe/Paris.

Comment: Список доступных зон: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneId.html#SHORT_IDS

Answer (score 0):

1. Это не ошибка компиляции, а run-time ошибка во время выполнения
2. Это штатное поведение `ZoneId.of()`, который [согласно документации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html#of-java.lang.String-) может выкидывать 2 исключения: *DateTimeException - if the zone ID has an invalid format* и *ZoneRulesException - if the zone ID is a region ID that cannot be found*

Вам нужно:

1. Корректно обрабатывать исключение, через `catch(ZoneRulesException ex)`
2. Подавать на вход корректную тайм-зону (в комментариях указали варианты)